# Store and perform search on large size of text in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-textract

I have a requirement to get OCR(Optical character recognition) data from PDFs and images files in S3 so that user can perform search on that OCR data. I am using AWS Textract for text extraction to get OCR data.

I was planning to store the OCR data in Dynamo DB and perform search query in that.

Issue that I am facing is because of the size limit of dynamo db items which is limited to 400KB.

I have situation where user upload 100+ MB PDF file in S3 where the extracted text content will exceed this limit. So what is the best approach in this case.

Please help
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you could still use DynamoDB, you would just need to split the data up across multiple items. In this case, your partition key might be the PDF file key/name and the sort key might be some kind of part key. You can then get all items containing text for the file using Query (rather then GetItem).

DynamoDB gets really expensive when you're dealing with a lot of data so another option could be S3 and Athena:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/

Basically, you write the OCR data to a text file and store that in S3. You can then use Athena to run queries over that data. This solution is very flexible and is likely to be much cheaper than DynamoDB. There might be some downsides in performance.

Comment: Can we consider AWS Elastic search for this?

Comment: Yes, its certainly possible. Elastic search can be expensive as you have to run a server all the time. Athena is serverless so you only pay for what you use.